# eclipse plugins not visible

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, google-eclipse-plugin

I have recently installed gwt-plugin to my eclipse. But plugins are are not visible, even if I try to install it again, eclipse is not allowing me to install, saying its already installed.I even I ran eclipse as administrator(I am using it in windows 7) and also with clean option, nothing worked out.

And one more thing, After GWT installation, it gave two options - 'Restart' and 'Apply changes'.I have chosen 'Restart'. (Does it matter?)

Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you installed gwt-plugin correctly, but you are missing one of its dependencies?  Take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489648/eclipse-doesnt-load-plugins-in-the-dropins-folder/3295170#3295170).  One of the answers discusses using the OSGI console to locate missing dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..There are no missing dependencies.By the way, I installed it through update site.