# Eclipse plugin not working

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have the eclipse Indigo ans I am trying to install the Axis 2 WSDLtoJava plugin.
Normaly, i have to paste the .jar file in the dropins folder, but nothing happens, the plugin is not installed...

Answer (score 2):

The dropins folder can be tricky. Sometimes it just wont work, [no matter what you try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513747/plugins-in-dropins-catalog-are-not-found). Ideally, you should look for an update site that contains the plugin you need. Have you checked if Axis isnt a part of the Indigo Update site?

If you fail to find an update site, you can copy the file to the plugins folder.

**Update:** If you still cannot find the plugin, it probably lacks some dependencies. Check the state of the plugin, see [Dude, where's my bundle?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Where_Is_My_Bundle) for more info on states of plugins.

The webpage doesn't mention the "Plugin Registry" view, where you can view a plugin and its states from within Eclipse. You can even diagnose a plugin to see why it doesn't start.

As for installing Axis2, it is on the Eclipse update site:

> http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo

Search for "Axis2". Not sure if that contains exactly the feature you are after though, but worth a test.

Comment: Thanks for the aswer Fredrik, I allready copied the .jar file to the plugins folder but nothing happens.
How to see if axis is in one of the indigo update website?

Comment: @MilosCuculovic Updated to answer the comment