# Dropins folder does not find new bundles automatically

Tags: eclipse, osgi, bundle, eclipse-kepler

eclipse kepler, in my case: D:\Eclipse Kepler\dropins, does not locate new bundles in the dropins folder. I tried a lot of methods described on official sites, for example starting eclipse with: eclipse -clean -console -consoleLog -debug /path/to/.options

"Create an .options file with the following content:
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core/debug=true
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core/reconciler=true"

It does not work. All the bundles i copied in dropins folder wont detect by eclipse, so i cant find this bundles in OSGI RunConfiguration. On the other side, if i manually edit the bundles.info (in my case: "D:\Eclipse Kepler\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator\bundles.info"), it would show me the bundle, which i inserted into bundles.info, in OSGI RunConig. But i dont want to edit manually all the time because of time-wasting. Does anyone have an idea?

Thanx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse, dropins, console mode, Axis2 and dropins not installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848290/eclipse-dropins-console-mode-axis2-and-dropins-not-installed)