# Failed to install Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have put the plugin jar files under dropins folder (Indigo), the plugin never load as expected as I close and restart Eclipse.

What log I can check to see the error?

I am using Mac.

Comment: What plugin are you trying to install? Is it available through the Eclipse Package Manager instead?

Comment: dropins is a totally optional, silently failing leftover.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513747/plugins-in-dropins-catalog-are-not-found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try to launch eclipse using the -clean option?
Where did you get the jar files from?

Try following:

1. Move all plugin files under dropins to other directory.
2. Make new workspace, and launch eclipse
3. Close eclipse
4. Put all plugin files back in place.
5. Open the workspace you have created at #2.