# Plug-In not taking affect in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jar

I have created a plugin project in eclipse to create a new category and view. I run the MANIFEST.MF file as an eclipse application which opens a new eclipse window and I can see my plugin take affect. However, I want the plugin to be part of my standard eclipse installation.

For this I have exported the project to a jar, put the jar in the plugins folder and restarted eclipse. But I cannot see the changes take affect. I have also tried running eclipse from the command prompt with -clean option to force eclipse to search for new plugins. I have also tried putting the jar file in the dropins folder and restarting but nothing is working.

Any idea on what I might be missing ? I know the other option is to create feature but I wanted to understand what is wrong or missing in my approach.

Regards,
    Dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try starting Eclipse with OSGI console (`eclipse -console`) and see if it gives any errors or warnings.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489648/eclipse-doesnt-load-plugins-in-the-dropins-folder/3295170#3295170) on SO.

Comment: The commands you would want to run in the console are: `ss` to list all plugins that have been found and `diag <name/number of the plugin>`

Comment: Hello Hemal...thanks a lot for your guidance, it really helped. The problem was that my manifest file was corrupt, so corrected it. Thanks once again.