# Installing AspectJ Development Tools plugin (AJDT) into Eclipse

Tags: aspectj, ajdt

I am trying to install the AspectJ Development Tools plugin (AJDT) into Eclipse (v3.8).

My goal is to achieve the results illustrated on this web page:  https://www.gorillalogic.com/monkeytalk-documentation/monkeytalk-getting-started/install-agent/android.
I have tried the methods described on this web page http://www.venukb.com/2006/08/20/install-eclipse-plugins-the-easy-way/.

To no avail.  The install/uninstall dialog in eclipse indicates that the plugins have been seen by eclipse but I am not getting the desired result of the menu items appearing.  I have also used the dropins folder.  I am obviously doing something wrong.

I have looked at similar questions, such as [Eclipse doesn't load plugins in the dropins folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489648/eclipse-doesnt-load-plugins-in-the-dropins-folder) still to no avail.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend using the dropins folder as it does not support all of the things that AJDT needs to do when it installs.

You can check that the plugins are installed by going to Help -> About Eclipse... Or Eclipse -> About Eclipse on macs.

If AJDT is properly installed, you will see the AJ icon in the dialog.  Next, make sure JDT weaving is enabled. Go to Preferences -> JDT weaving to see.

If either of these things show troubles, then look at your error log.  And see if you had any trouble installing.