# Eclipse plugin not visible

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

im not sure whether its an issue with the plugin or eclipse.Recently im working on this plugin and i was using Indigo /JavaSE7 .When i launch it as an eclipse application im getting my plugin on top. I also exported it as a plugin(export>deployable plugins...) and put in the plugins folder, it is visible and working fine.I tried putting it in Eclipse/Galileo in my machine and it works fine.The problem is  When my colleague puts this jar in Eclipse /Indigo Plugins folder(Any other system apart from mine)  it is not visible and not even any signs of it.
i'm not sure if it has some thing to do with the JRE/SDK,please help me out.
Im attaching the manifest file if anything missing:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: XTechnologySolutions
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.xquery.review.plugin; singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: com.xquery.review.plugin.Activator
Bundle-Vendor: CognizantTechnologySolutions
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.core.resources;bundle-version="3.7.101",
 org.eclipse.ui.ide
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-ClassPath: src/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar,
 .,
 src/lib/XQueryReview.jar
Import-Package: org.eclipse.jface.text
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
```

thanks in advance ...

Comment: You should try using an update-site to deploy your plug-in instead of the drop-in / plug-in folder (which is unreliable).
It's not hard to do, and it will fetch dependencies as needed.

Comment: thanks scawf!!! i got the issue , it was because of this bundle org.eclipse.core.resources;bundle-version="3.7.101"  where i have added it as require bundle...Once i moved it to Import-package issue resolved. I think these issues will not popup if i use an update-site....

Comment: In fact with an update site, there would have been a nice popup saying something like "org.eclipse.core.resources-3.7.101 cannot be installed ". But it's great if it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the answers from this Stackoverflow post... has good information on how to debug plugin loading issues

[Eclipse doesn't load plugins in the dropins folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489648/eclipse-doesnt-load-plugins-in-the-dropins-folder)