# While installing plugin in Eclipse Luna, "Unable to acquire PluginConverter service" and "No repository found" errors appear in logs

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am using `Luna` version of `Eclipse EE` eclipse-jee-luna-M1-win32-x86_64 and trying to place the tomcat plugin (`EclipseTotale` - com.sysdeo.eclipse.tomcat_3.3.0) inside the dropins folder. When the tomcat icons didn't show up, I checked the eclipse logs, and it showed :

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.eclipse 4 0 2013-09-12 20:19:53.571
!MESSAGE Unable to acquire PluginConverter service during generation for: C:\Programs\eclipse-jee-luna-M1-win32-x86_64\eclipse\dropins\com.sysdeo.eclipse.tomcat_3.3.0.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core 4 0 2013-09-12 20:19:53.581
!MESSAGE Provisioning exception
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: No repository found at file:/C:/Programs/eclipse-jee-luna-M1-win32-x86_64/eclipse/dropins/com.sysdeo.eclipse.tomcat_3.3.0/.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.fail(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:692)
```

The same plugin used to work perfectly for `Juno` (and `Kepler`). Any ideas ?

Answer (score 21):

In case anyone else (like me) is trying to install a plugin that is unlikely to get updated for a while...

You can add the legacy "Eclipse 2.0" plugin support from the "Eclipse Tests, Examples, and Extras" category in the Luna updates repository. See the attachment to [this comment](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=413006#c3), which you can eventually find by tracing the breadcrumbs from the link in Dan Dar3's answer.

You can also add the legacy plugin support like so from the command line:

```
./eclipse -nosplash -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director \
    -repository http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4/ \
    -installIU org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.plugins.feature.feature.group
```

After that, older plugins should install successfully.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me with the ResourceBundle editor 0.8.0.

Comment: Awesome! That really made work.
Just want to link with this question that says how to debug plugin loading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489648/eclipse-doesnt-load-plugins-in-the-dropins-folder

Comment: Last piece of a 3 day struggle to get Sharpen built and installed. Thank you.

Comment: Excellent, helped installing fatjar into luna (just copy the jar into "plugins" and run the command from Nemos post)

Comment: Just for your interest: A maintained version of the "old" Sysdeo Tomcat plugin can now be found at http://tomcatplugin.sf.net. There is also an update site available: http://tomcatplugin.sf.net/update

Answer (score 3):

I think the cause is to be found in this Eclipse 4.4 Luna change, which went into M1.
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=407312

> For Luna we are considering removing the plugin converter support that
>   allowed Eclipse 2.0 old-style plugins to run unchanged.  There types
>   of plugins have no OSGi bundle manifest (only a plugin/fragment xml
>   file).

Have contacted Sysdeo and Bruno Leroux was kind to provide an updated package which seems to work fine with Eclipse 4.4 RC3 (plugin v3.3.1) although he had no plans to support development for the plugin any further (12 years old). He's also waiting for feedback from other two other users and then he'll make the updated publicly available.

~~~

Version 3.3.1 of the plugin to support Eclipse 4.4 Luna is now publicly available.
http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html

Comment: I have forked the plugin some time ago as we still do heaviliy use the plugin in my company: http://tomcatplugin.sf.net

Answer (score 1):

For anyone trying to fix this problem.  I used the eclipse plugin converter on this plugin which creates a META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file from the old plugin.xml file.  This makes the above error disappear, however the plugin still does not work, but now there is no error message in the eclipse logs...  I know nothing about plugin development so if anyone has any ideas let me know.

Answer (score 0):

For individual plug-ins, put them in dropins/plugins, not dropins directly.

Comment: there is no 'dropins/plugins' folder.. '/' is not allowed in names.. or do u mean anything else

Comment: A directory named "plugins" inside the dropins directory.

Comment: I think he means eclipse\dropins\com.sysdeo.eclipse.tomcat_3.3.0 but I don't think that is the problem. Yes, it used to work up and including Eclipse 4.3.2, but not with Eclipse 4.4 (any milestones and now release candidates). I'm in the process of contacting Sysdeo with details about it see if they have any plans to fix it (http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html).

Comment: Well, that Plugin should have been forked years ago. It is so useful yet would still be worth a thousand additions. And the support... forget it. I never received as much as a single reply when pointing out incompatibilities, or the like.